# OnSubmit return doesn´t work in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, forms, safari

I have a form with:

```
onSubmit="return myFunction()"
```

And in my script:

```
function myFunction(){
  alert("hello world");
  return false;
}
```

I have checked in Crhome and Firefox, everything works perfect, but in Safari it doesn´t call to myFunction, neither the alert.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Is javascript enabled? (also check the console output)

Comment: You may have a javascript error that disables your javascript, check the console.

Comment: I´m executing others scripts on my Safari browser. The problem is just with onSubmit.

Comment: `onsubmit` should be all lowercase

Comment: OMG, is correct :S, I can´t believe this =(, I have lost 40 minutos looking for anwers to this. Thanks Li Yin.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching this to your form :

```
onsubmit="javascript:myFunction()"
```

I tested it in Safari and It was working for me. I hope this helped you!

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn´t work when I return a false from myFunction(); It makes the submit always.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
document.myForm.onsubmit = function( e ) {
alert("hello world");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can do like this and it will work in all browsers.

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens prior to   the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler.

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)